# Do I need stationary time series for Bayesian structural time series (BSTS)?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

I'm trying to model with BSTS, with exogenous variables.

It appears that my y-sequence is not stationary. Do I need to diff that to stationary? Or could BSTS handle that?

P.S. I'm using R package bsts

Thank you for your time!

All the best,

Kathy

Comment: You might have better luck asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ since the question is more about the appropriateness of a model rather than programming.